# If we built a large moon close to Mars, could we make Mars a living world?

Tags: space, moons, planets, life

If we made a large moon near Mars, the tidal forces would encourage the tectonic system to rev up again, and start up the inner dynamo effect. There would be volcanoes, producing a new atmosphere, which would capture more of the sun's heat and promote warm humid conditions for life.

To make the moon, it would be necessary to merge Phobos and Deimos and to figure out a domino effect among large bodies of the solar system which would send them all into the same orbit of Mars somewhere where they would join up.

Would we be able to make Mars have oceans again?

What technology plans could we develop to make a new moon possible?

Comment: What level of technology do you have in mind? Remember: Sufficiently advanced technology tends to be indistinguishable from magic.

Comment: I bet it will be easier to paint Mars black.

Comment: I should probably erase the second question because it is probably already on the forum.

Comment: @AntoineHejlík let me guess: You see a red Mars and you want it painted black?

Comment: @dot_Sp0T +1 for the The Rolling Stones reference. :D

Comment: @comprehensible There are plenty of suggestions for how Mars can be terraformed... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terraforming_of_Mars ....but I cannot see that **creating a new moon** is among them.

Comment: @dot_Sp0T You know, so less sunlight gets reflected, it heats up and then...

Comment: Phobos and Deimos are tiny. Compared to the size of our moon they are a rounding error.

Comment: Apparently our own moon helps with our own magnetosphere. I assume that's where your idea came from. Not being anything near an expert, it still sounds feasible to my layman's ears. It might not be particularly fast, though...

Comment: Probably easier just to crash that mass into mars and let the impact kick things up a bit?

Comment: Why build a moon?  Just move Ceres into orbit around Mars.  Avoids all the messy splattering effects of smashing small asteroids into each other.

Comment: The question doesn't really make much sense. A lack of a moon isn't what's stopping Mars from being habitable. It wouldn't start up the core again either, at least none of the papers I've read on the subject suggest this.

Comment: Ok good point. The Earth Moon barycenter is located on average 4,671 km from the Earth's center and it moves the land surface upwards by several kilometers, and has a big effect on the metal core, venus has more metal and has simple convection and supervolcanos and no magnetosphere and not a lot of hydrogen. Also the sea and earth tides may push the tectonic plates and without the moon, the hydrology would have made the earth a water world or an ice world. the moon was originally 5/10 times larger in the sky. Venus and Mercury only has the tidal force of the sun and jupiter, no moons.

Comment: Sorry the moon moves the rock material by about 30cm not meters.  It's fascinating to query if we could have a strong magnetosphere and hydrogen without the moon and what the earth would be like without a moon, and even if the tides encourage tectonic displacement.

Comment: It doen't need to be a moon, one/two fusion reactor/s orbiting Mars and powerful enough could do the trick as well (as suggested by E. Musk).

Comment: Rocky zones like the moon and mars are actually better for robots than our planet, less humidity, less biological interference, calmer climate, bright skies for solar energy... some kinds of robots could dig the entire planet into mines and livable spaces, if we can make robots that mine resources and self replicate themselves.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Assuming that you are right that a large moon could actually gets Mars tectonic and magnetic system working again...** (which is an interesting idea)
So after merging Phobos and Deimos and getting them in the right orbit, take the [four largest asteroids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_exceptional_asteroids) in our solar system and send probes to them. Set up some nuclear reactors and a lot of [EM drives](http://www.sciencealert.com/it-s-official-nasa-s-peer-reviewed-em-drive-paper-has-finally-been-published) and put them on a transfer orbit to Mars.
Several years/decades go by while the delta V for all that mass is adjusted and the transfer happens, and during that time the asteroids can be shaped by robots to fit better together. While the new moons gravity will have an effect on Mars, Mars will also have an effect on the new moon, and tidal forces could break it apart, which would be [disastrous for any teraforming plans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seveneves). Having the pieces fit together could make permanently fusing them much easier.

Once a magnetic field has been restarted, which will help deflect solar rays and keep them from removing the atmosphere, you need to make an atmosphere. 
Get a bunch of ice chunks and send them toward Mars the same way. These you can impact into Mars in the [Borealis basin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_Polar_Basin_(Mars)), as that area will all be under water eventually anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You could just 'magic' the moon into existence.  It's not like there was any technology involved in the creation of any existing moon.  It's possible that a small rogue planetoid we haven't noticed just so happens to be on the perfect trajectory to wind up orbiting Mars.  It would surely have a substantial effect on Mars' orbit and surface for a while while this interaction settled in, but hey, why not?